# li and p horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

One of the issues I'm facing now is that I have a flexbox(which should be irrelevant) with an inner div that's horizontally centered in the parent. I want an unordered list to be aligned horizontally with the text in the inner div, but even with text-align: center, it seems to be off by a couple of pixels(to the right) and I cannot figure out why(I can't believe I've never ran into this problem up until now). The '.right' div is actually a child of another element, but that should be irrelevant, so I'll just post the part I actually need. Is this just a product of the ul's initial styles?

```css
.right {
  text-align: center;
  order: 2;
  //background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right .headbox{
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

.right .list{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.headbox h3{
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  
  <div class="headbox">
    <h3>Visit Us</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Overview</li>
      <li>Hours</li>
      <li>Admission</li>
      <li>Directions</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `padding: 0` to your `<ul>` to override the browser's default styling.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<ul>` still have the default padding from the browser's default stylesheet.

You can use the `padding-left: 0;` to disable that padding.

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
.right {
  text-align: center;
  order: 2;
  //background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right .headbox{
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

.right .list{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.headbox h3{
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">

  <div class="headbox">
    <h3>Visit Us</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Overview</li>
      <li>Hours</li>
      <li>Admission</li>
      <li>Directions</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```